# Kotlin/Native How to use NSInvocation in KotlinNative

Tags: objective-c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I want to use NSInvocation but argument and return value need cpoint.

```
        val selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName)
        val signature = obj.methodSignatureForSelector(selector) ?: return null
        val invocation = NSInvocation.invocationWithMethodSignature(signature as NSMethodSignature)
        invocation.setSelector(selector)
        invocation.setTarget(obj)
        args.forEachIndexed { index, any ->
            println(index)
            println(any)
            val stableRef = StableRef.create(any as NSObject)
            val voidPtr = stableRef.asCPointer()
            any.toCPoingter
            invocation.setArgument(any, (index + 2).toLong())
        }
        invocation.invoke()
        val returnValue: Any? = null
        invocation.getReturnValue(returnValue.ptr)
        return returnValue
```

Could you give me a demo?